# Удалить символ из последнего элемента в массиве

Tags: php

Добрый вечер. На выходе получаю массив из 10 строк, например. Как можно удалить последнюю запятую из последней (10-ой) строчки?

```
foreach($html as $e) {
    echo '{"comment":"'.$value.' серия", "file":"'.$link.'"}, ';
}
```

Comment: на выходе из чего? $e[9] = substr($e[9], 0, -1)); ?

Comment: вы хотите последнюю запятую убрать? :)

Comment: @gm-111, поверьте, вам не нужны все эти костыли. Просто используйте `json_encode`.

Answer (score 4):

То что вы хотите сделать называется [implode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php) на самом деле

```
$r = array();
$html =  array( 
  1 => 'blah',
  4 => 'herp',
  6 => 'derp',
  2 => 'bleep');

foreach($html as $value => $link) {
  $r[] = '{"comment":"'.$value.' серия", "file":"'.$link.'"}';
}

echo implode(', ', $r);
```

на выходе:

```
{"comment":"1 серия", "file":"blah"}, {"comment":"4 серия", "file":"herp"}, {"comment":"6 серия", "file":"derp"}, {"comment":"2 серия", "file":"bleep"}
```

Ну и чтоб два раза не вставать, **на самом деле** вы хотели сделать [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php) (чтоб избежать проблем с экранированием символов):

```
$html =  array( 
  array( "comment" => "1 серия", "file" => "blah"),
  array( "comment" => "5 серия", "file" => "herp"),
  array( "comment" => "4 серия", "file" => "derp"),
  array( "comment" => "3 серия", "file" => "dong"),
);

echo json_encode($html, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Comment: Черт, вот на секунду опередил.

Comment: Простите, вечерний отдых от java. :)

Comment: Мало того, что последнюю запятую не удаляет, так еще и вперед добавляет две, кроме первой строки)

Comment: в моем коде нет запятой последней в строке и в Вашем не должно быть @gm-111  Я не знаю что у вас там за $value // $link.. сейчас поправлю чтоб было рабочим.

Comment: И в правду у вас нет, попробуе без запятой. А в этих переменных число, а во второй ссылка.

Comment: @gm-111, по возможности старайтесь избегать ручной сборки всяких XML и JSON особенно если для этого есть  библиотеки. Там слишком много подводных камней, об которые для Вас уже другие люди побились  :)

Comment: @DmitryV., убрал запятую, все работает, спасибо. Ну не знаю, в этом случае легко, а большего мне и не надо :)

Comment: И за **json_encode** тоже спасибо, позже попробую)

Comment: до первого странного бага в продакшне, когда кто-то в имени файла напишет "} или чего похуже, @gm-111. Хотя если источник данных доверенный - ничего особо страшного, просто лишний код.

Comment: @DmitryV. так а все, шаблон сделан, парсер тоже. Парсер вставляет ссылки в массив сам, так что проблем не будет. Мне лишь остается вставлять ссылки в поле формы :)